# Custom Section in Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to create and use a custom section in web.config ?

Comment: you seem to be missing the example from the web config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of the ability to extend `.config` files that is in .NET (from V2) using `System.Configuration` assembly.

See examples on my blog: http://blog.rjcox.co.uk/2010/05/21/custom-configuration-2/

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Jon Rista's three-part series on .NET 2.0 configuration up on CodeProject.

- [Unraveling the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)
- [Decoding the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)
- [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

Highly recommended, well written and extremely helpful!

Also, there's a Visual Studio Add-in called [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com) up on Codeplex which is really quite helpful - it allows you to visually design your own custom config sections and have the necessary code and XML schema generated for you.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Use configuration section designer

http://csd.codeplex.com/

It helps you create and use custom sections. It's quite awesome.